# How does Freetext() work in Indexing Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, indexing-service

This is my query I use in a ASP.NET(C#) test-application:

```
SELECT Filename,Size,PATH,Characterization,Rank,Create 
FROM  testCatalog..Scope('Deep traversal of "\\D\myCatalogFolder"') 
WHERE Freetext('test')
ORDERBY Rank DESC
```

I thought it works fine until I checked the results more deeply. 
I recognized that there are a lot of results which don't have a single occurrence of 'test'!
How can I fix my query to only get results that match my search?

Is there any Indexing Service Expert out there who can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FREETEXT Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx)

`FREETEXT` does not look for the specific string; it attempts to find occurrences of the string or something with equivalent *meaning*. If you just want to search for a specific word or phrase, use `CONTAINS`.

```
WHERE CONTAINS(Column, 'text')
```

Comment: Sorry :) it seems you where right! I had a second problem. I had a "OR" in the where- statement so I found all occurrences of my word as well as a lot of other stuff...